# How to get notified efficiently when an OAuth response is received?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, ionic-framework, firebase

I am using [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) with [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) to have Facebook and Google sign in. I have 2 service `FirebaseService.js`, `AppService.js` and a controller `dashboard.js`. I need to get the OAuth response in this controller.

What is the best way to do this? I have come across this type of scenerio in couple of other places so looking for an efficient way to do this.

My approach which I used in other places is to have a notifier (notifier gets called when data is available) and listener

```
/** notify for Auth data response */
this.authDataAvailable = function() {
    $rootScope.$emit("auth-data-available");
}
/** subscribe to this listener when the aggregated data response is available */
this.authDataAvailableListener = function(scope, callback, isDestroy) {
    var handler = $rootScope.$on("auth-data-available", callback);
    if (isDestroy)
        scope.$on("$destroy", handler);
}

/** subscribing to the above listener */
$scope.authDataResponseListener($scope, function responseAvailable() {
    //auth response available at this point
}, true);
```

FirebaseService.js

```
function FirebaseService($q) {
    this.appRef;
    this.authData; //.provider: ["facebook"||"google"], facebook.displayName || google.displayName, facebook.id || google.id, facebook.profileImageURL || google.profileImageURL

    this.getRef = function() {
        return this.appRef;
    }
    this.authWithOAuthPopup = function(type) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        this.appRef = new Firebase("https://lola.firebaseio.com");
        this.appRef.authWithOAuthPopup(type, function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                this.authError = error;
                switch (error.code) {
                    case "INVALID_EMAIL":
                        console.log("The specified user account email is invalid.");
                        break;
                    case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
                        console.log("The specified user account password is incorrect.");
                        break;
                    case "INVALID_USER":
                        console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("Error logging user in:", error);
                }
                deferred.resolve(this.authError);
            } else {
                this.authData = authData;
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
                deferred.resolve(this.authData);
            }
        });
                deferred.promise;
    }

    /**
     * Write or replace data to a defined path, like messages/users/<username>
     */
    this.set = function(child, obj) {
        var childRef = this.appRef.child(child);
        childRef.set(obj);
    }

    return {
        getRef: this.getRef,
        authWithOAuthPopup: this.authWithOAuthPopup
    }
}
angular.module("starter.services", []).service('FirebaseService', FirebaseService);
```

AppService.js

```
function AppService(FirebaseService, $rootScope) {
    this.authData; //.provider: ["facebook"||"google"], facebook.displayName || google.displayName, facebook.id || google.id, facebook.profileImageURL || google.profileImageURL

    /** notify for Auth data response */
    this.authDataAvailable = function() {
        $rootScope.$emit("auth-data-available");
    }
    /** subscribe to this listener when the aggregated data response is available */
    this.authDataAvailableListener = function() {
        var handler = $rootScope.$on("auth-data-response", callback);
        if (isDestroy)
            scope.$on("$destroy", handler);
    }

    this.authenticateWithGoogle = function() {
        this.authData = FirebaseService.authWithOAuthPopup("google");
        this.authDataAvailable();
        console.log(this.authData.google.displayName);
    }

    this.authenticateWithFacebook = function() {
        this.authData = FirebaseService.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook");
        this.authDataAvailable();
        console.log(this.authData.facebook.displayName);
    }

    this.getAuthData = function() {
        return this.authData;
    }

    return {
        authenticateWithGoogle: this.authenticateWithGoogle,
        authenticateWithFacebook: this.authenticateWithFacebook,
        getAuthData: this.getAuthData            
    }
}

angular.module('starter.services').service('AppService', AppService);
```

dashboard.js

```
function DashCtrl($scope, AppService) {
    $scope.user = "";
    $scope.openBrowser = function() {
        AppService.authenticateWithFacebook();
        /*var authData = AppService.getAuthData();
        $scope.user = authData.facebook.displayName;
        console.log(authData);
        console.log($scope.user);*/
    }
}

angular.module("starter.controllers", []).controller('DashCtrl', DashCtrl);
```

In my approach I get `this.authDataAvailable is not a function` error in `AppService.js` statement `this.authDataAvailable();` under `this.authenticateWithFacebook` function.

Please help me in knowing an effective way or best practice to achieve these kind of scenarios.

**Update**

So I came across 2 things that helped in solving my problem with help from mJunaidSalaat.

1. Using something like below in my AppService.js

   ```
   this.authenticateWithFacebook = function() {
       FirebaseService.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook")
       .then(function(data) {
           service.authData = data;
           console.log(this.authData);
           service.authDataAvailable();
           console.log(this.authData.facebook.displayName);
       }, function(err) {
           console.log(err)
       });
    }
   ```
2. Using a identifier for `this` as inside any enclosure it changes the context. So used `service` in my case.

Comment: in `this.authenticateWithFacebook` function are you receiving `this.authData`? I mean try logging it our like `console.log(this.authData)`

Comment: @mJunaidSalaat: no I am getting `undefined` for `console.log(this.authData);` in `this.authenticateWithFacebook` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `FirebaseService.js` the callback function is not returning the received data promise. Try adding

```
this.authWithOAuthPopup = function(type) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        this.appRef = new Firebase("https://lola.firebaseio.com");
        this.appRef.authWithOAuthPopup(type, function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                this.authError = error;
                switch (error.code) {
                    case "INVALID_EMAIL":
                        console.log("The specified user account email is invalid.");
                        break;
                    case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
                        console.log("The specified user account password is incorrect.");
                        break;
                    case "INVALID_USER":
                        console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("Error logging user in:", error);
                }
                deferred.resolve(this.authError);
            } else {
                this.authData = authData;
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
                deferred.resolve(this.authData);
            }
        });
        return defered.promise;//this returns the promise rejected or resolve with the supplied data
    }
```

and in `AppService.js` handle the promise like

```
this.authenticateWithFacebook = function() {
        var service = this;
        FirebaseService.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook")
          .then(function(data){
            this.authData = data
            console.log(this.authData.facebook.displayName);
            service.authDataAvailable();
          },function(err){
              console.log(err)
          });
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added `return deferred.promise;` after `});` and it returns an empty promise, with status as 0. I am also updating m question.

Comment: Yeah sorry it was my mistake. Corrected it. Thanks

Comment: @Ricky tell me one this. what does your `console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);` logs? Are you getting the `authData` object here?

Comment: I am getting `Authenticated successfully with payload: Object {provider: "facebook", uid: "facebook:1324428977082662", facebook: Object, token: "eyJ0eXAiOyJKV4QiLJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJwcm92aWRlc…sifX0.Re0LR7EzhX1VpqsnM1-z31mjHynEt4cqthZ8DjkGE90", auth: Object…}` but not able to get this info in `this.authenticateWithFacebook` function. Also `ionic.bundle.js:26771 TypeError: this.authDataAvailable is not a function` error stil persists

Comment: Have you tried my edited answer? And the error `ionic.bundle.js:26771 TypeError: this.authDataAvailable is not a function` cAme after it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112279/discussion-between-mjunaidsalaat-and-ricky).